# Handling a onreponse error in a Kotlin program

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to work out what's wrong with this code ? I'm new to this. I'm having a response error,

```
        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.URL_ADD_ARTIST,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                try {
                    val obj = JSONObject(response)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            object : Response.ErrorListener {
                override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("user", user)
                params.put("password", password)
                params.put("email", email)
                return params
            }
        }

        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
```

These lines are causing the error.

```
val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.URL_ADD_ARTIST,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
val obj = JSONObject(response)
```

Comment: Please consider adding the error stacktrace

Comment: Or the response error?